# Error importing ground control points ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photogrammetry, error-000735, ground-control

I am working on processing aerial images from an automated drone flight in ArcGIS Pro. The photos import into the Ortho Mapping workspace just fine, and the Quick Adjust alignment runs without problems (not all photos are displayed at this scale in the image below). However, when I try to import Ground Control Points via the Import GCPs tool, it fails with the error:

> ERROR 000735: Target Control Points: Value is required

The only parameter value I don't have filled in on the tool dialogue is GCP Photo Location, which as far as I can tell is optional. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/add-gcps-to-your-ortho-mapping-workspace.htm

I have run this exact same operation in the past with the same dataset and did not encounter any problems. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the full Adjust tool in the Ortho Mapping toolbar BEFORE trying to append the GCPs solved the issue. After running Adjust, the Import GCPs tool worked just fine.

The Error 000735 code ArcGIS Pro threw before this doesn't seem to bear much relationship to the actual problem.